# Extract the desired report from the output of the device

Tags: output, device, thingsboard

We have the equipment for monitoring workspace occupancy on the Thingsboard. We would like to receive updates on space utilization during the available hours from 8 am to 8 pm every day. The device provides output in the form of 0 and 1 at irregular intervals of 5 seconds or 1080 seconds.

The output should provide us with the information on the number of minutes during which the value was 0 and the number of minutes during which the value was 1 within a 12-hour period each day.

The time chart is given, but we want it to return the time value (minutes) 0 or 1 during the time interval.